# Secured views in SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, security, ssas

We have an SSAS 2012 instance containing a series of measure tables and dimension tables. One of the dimension tables relates to a client and serves to organise information by client.

Recently we were given the requirement that one client should be secured from view from another, i.e, users would be given 'access' to a given client and can therefore only view that client's data.

I wondered what the best way or achieving this goal would be. Currently anyone could create a pivot in excel for any client. I can only see the possibility of creating and securing seperate databases and ultimately separate cubes for each client.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some information posted on tecnet

[role management on SSAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500251.aspx)

To be specific i think the part [granting cell permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175408.aspx) is what you will be mostly interested on. Be aware that setting said permissions requires knowledge on MDX queries.

Comment: I had to use OLAP roles once for security and it was horrible. I'd really encourage you to investigate other methods as much as you can. If you end up looking at roles, be sure you research 'Visual Totals' carefully.